# JAXB with XmlAdapter for List to Map. Does not marshall as expected but outputs object details

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a requirement to convert a list (gadgets) to map. Hence using XmlAdapter.

**Schema**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
                targetNamespace="http://jaxb.com/schema" xmlns:test="http://jaxb.com/schema">

                <xs:element name="Person">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="gadgets" type="test:GadgetMapModeller" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

                <xs:complexType name="GadgetMapModeller">
                    <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="value" type="test:gadget"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>

                <xs:complexType name="gadget">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="make" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="model" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="year" type="xs:int"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>

                <xs:complexType name="Computer">
                    <xs:complexContent>
                        <xs:extension base="test:gadget">
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="speed" type="xs:int"/>
                                <xs:element name="cpu" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:complexContent>
                </xs:complexType>

            </xs:schema>
```

**Adapter**

```
            package com.jaxb;

            import java.util.Map;

            import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

            import com.jaxb.schema.Gadget;
            import com.jaxb.schema.GadgetMapModeller;

            public class GadgetMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<GadgetMapModeller, GadgetMap<String,Gadget>>
            { 
              @Override
              public GadgetMap<String,Gadget> unmarshal(GadgetMapModeller modeller)
              {
                GadgetMap<String,Gadget> map = new GadgetMap<String,Gadget>();
                for (GadgetMapModeller.Entry e : modeller.getEntry())
                {
                  map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                }
                return map;
              }

              @Override
              public GadgetMapModeller marshal(GadgetMap<String,Gadget> map)
              {
                GadgetMapModeller modeller = new GadgetMapModeller();
                for (Map.Entry<String,Gadget> entry : map.entrySet())
                {
                  GadgetMapModeller.Entry e = new GadgetMapModeller.Entry();
                  e.setKey(entry.getKey());
                  e.setValue(entry.getValue());
                  modeller.getEntry().add(e);
                  System.out.println("entry.getValue()" + entry.getValue());
                }
                return modeller;
              }
            }
```

**GadgetMap**

```
        package com.jaxb;

        import java.util.HashMap;

        import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(GadgetMapAdapter.class)
        public class GadgetMap<String,Gadget> extends HashMap<String,Gadget>
        { 
        }
```

On debugging, i found that the XmlAdapter.marshal method is invoked & i could see the value of the object inside. But the output received is as follows.

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Person xmlns:ns2="http://jaxb.com/schema">
    <ns2:name>Matt Shannon</ns2:name>
    <ns2:gadgets>
        <entry>
            <key>my ipad</key>
            <value>
                <ns2:make>Apple</ns2:make>
                <ns2:model>iPod</ns2:model>
                <ns2:year>2002</ns2:year>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>my laptop</key>
            <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:Computer">
                com.jaxb.Computer@704f568
            </value>
        </entry>
    </ns2:gadgets>
</ns2:Person>
```

Why it does not marshall properly & produces - **com.jaxb.Computer@704f568**? Could you help me find out?

Answer (score 0):

Do yo have JAXBContext initialized properly (it must know about Computer), easiert is to have

```
@XmlSeeAlso(Computer.class)
public class Gadget {
...
}
```